# Putting a variable in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, c

Hey guys I'm trying to put a variable in a sql query but can't seem to get it to work. Below is my code, its an RFID reader which reads the value of a rfid tag. I want the value of the rfid tag to be stored in a database. How do i get the variable TagVal in the sql query? The TagVal variable needs to be in the spot where 1e00ad0ca9 value is(the 2nd query down below). Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <phidget21.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>


int CCONV TagHandler(CPhidgetRFIDHandle RFID, void *usrptr, char *TagVal, CPhidgetRFID_Protocol proto) //Tag wordt gelezen en LED gaat aan
      {
        CPhidgetRFID_setLEDOn(RFID, 1);


printf("Tag Read: %s\n", TagVal);
return 0;
}

int CCONV TagLostHandler(CPhidgetRFIDHandle RFID, void *usrptr, char *TagVal, CPhidgetRFID_Protocol proto) //Tag is verwijderd van RFID lezer
{
     CPhidgetRFID_setLEDOn(RFID, 0);

printf("Tag Lost: %s\n", TagVal);
return 0;
 }



int rfid_simple()
{
int result;
const char *err;

//Declare an RFID handle
CPhidgetRFIDHandle rfid = 0;

//RFID object wordt aangemaakt
CPhidgetRFID_create(&rfid);

//Wanneer de tag gelezen wordt, wordt het uitgeprint
CPhidgetRFID_set_OnTag2_Handler(rfid, TagHandler, NULL);

//Wanneer de tag  verwijderd wordt, wordt het uitgeprint
CPhidgetRFID_set_OnTagLost2_Handler(rfid, TagLostHandler, NULL);

//RFID wordt geopend voor connectie
CPhidget_open((CPhidgetHandle)rfid, -1);

//Programma wacht totdat RFID is aangesloten
printf("Waiting for RFID to be attached....\n");
if((result = CPhidget_waitForAttachment((CPhidgetHandle)rfid, 10000)))
{
    CPhidget_getErrorDescription(result, &err);
    printf("Problem waiting for attachment: %s\n", err);
    return 0;
}


CPhidgetRFID_setAntennaOn(rfid, 1);

//read RFID event data
printf("RFID reader is aangesloten! Druk op enter om het programma af te sluiten\n");

//keep displaying RFID event data until user input is read
printf("RFID tag nodig\n");
getchar();


//RFID wordt afgesloten zodra er op Enter wordt gedrukt
printf("Ik ga afsluiten vriend...\n");
CPhidget_close((CPhidgetHandle)rfid);
CPhidget_delete((CPhidgetHandle)rfid);

return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
MYSQL *conn;

    char *server = "x";
    char *user = "x";
    char *password = "x";
    char *database = "x";

// Make the connection to the Mysql-database on server.
  conn = mysql_init(NULL);
if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
     user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
  exit(1);
}

 //een insert into query : insert into tabelnaam VALUES(kolomnaam1, kolomnaam2, etc... )
 if (mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO Notifications(Notification_id, Notification) VALUES(NULL,'Open Deur')" )!=0)
  {exit(1);}

     if (mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO Access(Employee_id, Notification_id)VALUES('1e00ad0ca9',1)" )!=0)
     {exit(1);}

 /* close connection */
 mysql_close(conn);

rfid_simple();
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You have to use `mysql_prepare()` instead, and then `mysql_stmt_bind_value()`. It easier, and it prevents SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **sprintf** to build your string and easily concatenate your variables -- alternative to malloc/free.

```
  char buffer [1024];
  char *tagVal1 = "hello";
  char *tagVal2 = "world!";
  n=sprintf (buffer, "INSERT INTO Notifications(Notification_id, Notification) VALUES(%s,%s)", tagVal1, tagVal2);
  printf ("[%s] is a string %d chars long\n",buffer,n);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, where exactly do i declare the char *tagVal1? In my main with the mysql part or int CCONV TagHandler?

Comment: Looking at your code, you have TagVal as a parameter to the TagHandler() function.  An easy way is to declare a global variable, say char *_TagVal1; and inside TagHandler() assign the pointer like so:
 
printf("Tag Read: %s\n", TagVal);
_TagVal1 = tagVal1;

That way you can use _TagVal1 in main() to build your sql query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, ill try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Ok i have declared char *_TagVal1; as a global variable. How do i assign the pointer in TagHandler()?